# How to Install old Azure SDK via Microsft Web Platform installer?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

Is it possible to use the web plataform installer to install older versions of azure SDK?

Namely, I was trying to install azure sdk 2.8.2 but all my google-fu is giving me is links to this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50041 which are some manual instructions on how to install all the small parts...

Is there any way to achieve this with webPI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SDK for .NET 2.8.2 is missing in Microsoft Web Platform installer(WPI). We can't install this version of Azure SDK using WPI. All the available products of WPI will be list in following page.

https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/webproductlist.xml

If you did need to install this version of Azure SDK, you could download all the MSI files to your local and follow the instructions mentioned in the download page.

You also could execute the MSI files programmatically. Firstly We are able to use the /quiet or /qn options with msiexec to perform a silent install. Then we can use a batch file or other program languages to invoke msiexec command to install the MSI files in a loop.

> msiexec /i [msi-path] /quiet /qn /norestart /log [log-path]

Comment: Thanks, that was also my conclusion, just tried a last ditch attempt to ask anyone for a better solution.